# How do I change out the light bulb in this fixture?

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling, light-fixture

My wife picked up this light fixture at a sample sale. We had some electricians install it a while ago while we were having other work done on the apartment. The electricians threw out the box and paperwork, so I don't know the brand or model number. The glass "bowl" spins freely in the two metal side supports. You can also slide the bowl "back and forth" in the supports, but you can't slide it far enough to slide out of the supports. I can't move the supports at all. They don't just move out of the way to let the bowl fall out. I have tried turning the entire fixture, and I have also tried just pulling the fixture down. There is about one and one half inches of space between the ceiling and light fixture. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there any screws on the sides of the fixture? If so, try backing them out a bit, and seeing if the globe is released.

Comment: Thanks, Tester. Tried that already. There are two small pins on the sides of both metal supports.  (You cam barely see them in the first picture. Look at the left side support.) Unfortunately, that's all that they are-just pins. They hold the supports onto a crossbar. The pins do not have slots for a screwdriver, or openings for a hex wrench.

Comment: Maybe you push on the pins: are they springy?

Comment: Possibly you can just pull the fixture out, as Byrce suggested they could be spring clips. If you cannot see screws anywhere that will typically be the situation. But be careful when pulling the fixture, a sudden dislodge and you might drop the fixture or even worse fall of the ladder (chair) you are standing on. Try and leverage one side by applying pressure from the top (nearests to the ceiling) downwards and examine how it behaves. If hear a distinct crackling/scratching sound it means there are screws somewhere, so don't pull any more.

Comment: Thanks Bryce and ppumkin. I already tried pushing (and pulling) the pins, and I already tried pulling the entire fixture. I will try pulling (and pushing) the entire fixture again. Maybe there are springs in there somewhere.

Comment: can you contact the electricians and send them the image to help jog their memory?

Comment: Can you push up on one of the side supports?  If the crossbar has play, pushing one of the supports up may free one side of the glass, allowing you to pull it out.

Answer (score 1):

Take the photo to several lighting fixture stores and ask. The staff will often have wide knowledge of back catalog.